# How to enable Dark Mode (Red) for StandBy in Xcode Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

You can activate the StandBy mode in the Simulator by going to Features > Show StandBy. However, is there a way to apply a red color to it? On physical device you just make your environment dark.